# Should I create Apps for each Model in my django app?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have just learned python, and am beginning to make a web application using Django / DRF in the back end.

The back end would be similar to a CRUD, or just a CRUD actually, I'm not planning on doing too much processing on requests, but would be queuing jobs for another python script on the server to pick up when needed.

The API I'm building would need to manage a few different entities like Users, Packages, Transactions, Jobs etc, and I plan to manage all of these entities... no ... models... via a rest API.

Do I create an app for each model ? e.g. `user_app`, `package_app`, and `transaction_app` ? or should I create a single app to manage them all?

I'm torn between thinking of Django Apps as actual applications, or Bundles like in PHP/Symfony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no obligation to create a new app for every feature that depends on another part of the project logic.

But overall the more you divide into,  the easier it will be in the future.
when the project updated and new features added it will be easy to manage it.

Also take a look at some open source projects.